# Best approach for Archimedes problem? Linearization or KKT analysis

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am working through the following problem:

In $R^3$, consider a
sphere of radius r. If one makes a longitudinal cut (i.e., perpendicular to a radius) at a
distance r − h from the center, the cut-off portion has height h. Given a fixed surface area
A > 0 of the cut-off portion, find r and h to maximize the volume of the cut-off pieces.

This yields the nonlinear optimization problem:
\begin{align}
  \min_{r,h \in R} \quad  & -\pi h^2 (r-h/3) \\
  st \quad       & \ 2 \pi rh = A \\ 
  & \ r, h \ge 0.
 \end{align}

I found the Lagrangian:
$$ L(r,h,\mu_1) = -\pi h^2 (r - \frac{h}{3}) + \mu_1(2\pi r h-A)$$
and KKT conditions
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial r} = -\pi h^2 + 2\mu_1\pi h = -h^2 + 2\mu_1 h=0 $$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial h} = -2\pi r h + \pi h^2 + 2\mu_1\pi r = -2rh+h^2-2r\mu_1=0 $$
$$2\pi r h =A$$
$$\mu_1 \ge 0$$

Then I found a KKT point at $\mu_1 = \frac{1}{2}, h=1, r=1$. However, I couldnt find any more KKT points. The problem asks for an optimal solution. The problem is not convex optimization, so we can not say the KKT point is globally optimal. I tried to model the problem in Gurobi but couldn't linearize the objective function. How can I find the optimal solution to this nonlinear problem?

Comment: You have an error in the sign of $\ 2r\mu_1\ $ in the second expression in your equation for $\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial h}\ $, and your proposed KKT point doesn't satisfy the constraint $\ 2\pi rh=A\ $ (unless $\ A=2\pi\ $).  The only KKT point is, in fact, $\ r=h=\sqrt{\frac{A}{2\pi}}\ $, $\ \mu_1= 
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{A}{2\pi}}\ $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The simplest way of solving this problem is to use the constraint $\ 2\pi rh=A\ $ to reduce the dimension of the objective function's domain.  Substituting $\ r= \frac{A}{2\pi h}\ $ into the function $\ \pi h^2\left(r-\frac{h}{3}\right)\ $ reduces it to $ \frac{Ah}{2}-\frac{\pi h^3}{3}\ $.  There is a unique non-negative point at which the derivative of this function vanishes, and you should be able to show that this point is a maximum by investigating the sign of the derivative.

Comment: Thank you! The alternative form of the objective function makes the problem much easier to solve. I assume you meant to write substitute $r = \frac{A}{2\pi h}$ instead of "$r = \frac{A}{2\pi}$".

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for pointing out the error, now fixed.